# Combining Pair of Measures Used to Compute a Total Up a Hierarchy

Tags: powerbi, dax

I’m trying to compute the difference between (budget) allocations and expenditures.

At first glance, this seems easy to do with a simple measure:

```
Balance = SUM(Register[AllocationAmount]) – SUM(Register[TransactionAmount])
```

However, there’s an extra rule to factor in: Transaction amounts dated prior to the first allocation should be ignored. Measure `Balance` gets more complex to accommodate this:

```
Balance = CALCULATE(
  SUM(Register[AllocationAmount]) - SUM(Register[TransactionAmount]),
  FILTER(Dates, 
    Dates[Date] >= FIRSTDATE(Category[InitialAllocationDate]) 
    && NOT ISBLANK(FIRSTDATE(Category[InitialAllocationDate]))
  )
)
```

Unfortunately, `Balance` doesn't add up correctly when used to compute totals up a hierarchy in the Category table. This makes sense. When `Balance` is evaluated up the hierarchy, `FIRSTDATE(Category[InitialAllocationDate])` in the date filter pulls the first date out of *all* dates associated with *all* Category rows in context at that higher level and then uses this date to apply the filter *once* for the *entire* grouping.

This is incorrect. In order to produce an accurate total, the filter needs to be applied on a *per-Category basis* so that filtering factors in *each* category's `InitialAllocationDate`. To achieve this, I changed `Balance` so that it computes only when a single `Category[Name]` filter is applied (i.e. no hierarchy grouping is taking place). Then, I created a separate measure that uses `SUMX` to evaluate `Balance` on a per-Category row basis.

```
Balance = IF (HASONEFILTER(Category[Name])), 
  CALCULATE(
    SUM(Register[AllocationAmount]) - SUM(Register[TransactionAmount]),
    FILTER(Dates, 
      Dates[Date] >= FIRSTDATE(Category[InitialAllocationDate]) 
      && NOT ISBLANK(FIRSTDATE(Category[InitialAllocationDate]))
    )
  )
)

CumulativeBalance = SUMX(Grouping, Register[Balance])
```

This produces correct totals up Category's hierarchy (yay!); however, it requires two measures.

### Question

Is there a way I can eliminate the second measure (`CumulativeBalance`) and instead somehow adjust `Balance` so that it computes correctly up the hierarchy?